# Is there a filter to edit html of user-edit.php

Tags: wp-admin, users, admin-ui

I am looking for a filter to edit html of `user-edit.php` just before it is echoed. To be more specific, I need to disable selecting multiple roles in `Other Roles`. But this filter would be very handy for other stuff too. And for other admin pages as well.

Comment: there is no "Other Roles" in WordPress. it's certainly a plugin which add this. have you the extension "User Role Editor" e.g.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't know it's added by that plugin. I am using that exact plugin. But the question remains the same. How can i edit the HTML in admin.

Answer (score 1):

instead of editing the complet content, it's quicker to find the hook to remove

e.g. for the "other role" menu, you can use that :

```
add_action("wp_loaded", function () {

    remove_all_actions("edit_user_profile");

});
```

Comment: This is not exactly what i was looking for. I don't want to remove it completely. I just want to disable the multi select of it and probably just make it standard drop down (`<select><option>`). Essentially what I need to be able to add another user role to each user. But I might end up using your solution and adding custom code to it.